# How to serialize this to xml using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

Given this class

```
class Report {
   public String total;
   public Map monthly;

   public Report () {
      total = "10";
      monthly = new HashMap();
      monthly.put("MAR", 5);
      monthly.put("JUN", 5);
   } 
}
```

I would like to produce this XML:

```
<Report>
    <total>10</total>
    <MAR>5</MAR>
    <JUN>5</JUN>
</Report>
```

But it actually produces this XML:

```
 <Report>
     <total>10</total>
     <monthly>
         <MAR>5</MAR>
         <JUN>5</JUN>
     </monthly>
</Report>
```

If I add `@JsonIgnore` before `montly` declaration, the `montly` element goes away, but so does the `total`!?

```
<Report>
    <MAR>5</MAR>
    <JUN>5</JUN>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add accessor methods to your attributes and annotate `getMonthly` with `@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter`.

```
public class Report {

    private String total;

    private Map monthly;

    public Report () {
        total = "10";
        monthly = new HashMap<>();
        monthly.put("MAR", 5);
        monthly.put("JUN", 5);
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map getMonthly() {
        return monthly;
    }

}
```