# serialize and deserialize without map name

Tags: java, json

I have the following Object:

```
public class Class_a{
   private List<class_b> someList;
 }

public class Class_b{
   private Map<String,String> someMap;
 }
```

My json will look like this:

```
"someList":[{"someMap":{"strKey1":"strValue1"}},{"someMap":{"strKey2":"strValue2"}}]
```

Is it possible to serialize a Json that will look like this, without changing my Objects (and I will have the option to deserialize the Object):

```
"someList":[{"strKey1":"strValue1"},{"strKey2":"strValue2"}]
```

*I know that if will defined my object like this:

```
 public class Class_a{
   private List<Map<Strung,String>> someList;
 }
```

i will get a Json like I want - but I am trying to find more elegant solution then 'list' that contain a 'map'

My project use spring framework and Jackson.

Comment: I answered a similar question recently but the OP didn't accept the answer. See if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53136623/how-to-serialize-this-to-xml-using-jackson/53137087#53137087

Comment: Why don't you just try?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me I only had to add getters and setters to your classes and I was able to parse with jackson:

```
 @Test
    public void t() throws IOException {
        String json = "{\"someList\":[{\"someMap\":{\"strKey1\":\"strValue1\"}},{\"someMap\":{\"strKey2\":\"strValue2\"}}]}";
        Class_a a = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Class_a.class);

        System.out.println(a);

    }


@Getter
@Setter
public class Class_a{
   private List<Class_b> someList;
 }


@Getter
@Setter
public class Class_b{
    private Map<String,String> someMap;
}
```

I'm using lombok but that's nothing special, you can create the getters/setters manually too and will work

Comment: does it work for if: String json = "{\"someList\":[{\"strKey1\":\"strValue1\"},{\"strKey2\":\"strValue2\"}]}"?

Comment: it's not working so far, I tried Unwrap but doesn't seem to understand, maybe it needs custom deserializer. I'll try again and will update if got something working